# Resistance wire applied to mains blows fuse

Tags: circuit-design, resistance, heat

I have obtained a heating coil (FeCrAl) rated for 1000 W at a wire length of about 40 cm. The resistance from begin to end is 50 Ω. Applying mains (~230 V) to this wire makes the coil red hot, but within a minute the circuit breaker (16 A, B) steps in.

Applying Ohm's law to the above properties would indicate that 230 V divided by anything above 15 Ω should keep it below 16 A, given the properties of the wire without electricity applied is 50 Ω. That sounds to me to be in a safe ballpark (from a computer science background).

What am I missing here? Should I add an explicit resistor that is not influenced by temperature? Should the coil itself be stretched out prior to usage?

Comment: Any other load on the same circuit?

Comment: Insignificant, much less than 1A / 230W.

Comment: What if the heating coil is broken, and when it heats up some thermal expansion makes the coil turns to move and touch other metal parts, like make a short between turns or connect to earth?

Comment: what is the temperature coefficient of the alloy?

Comment: The heating coil is on a sand bed, so it does not touch any other metals. Regarding the temperature coefficients I have not been provided that within the datasheet. Can I compute that by applying different voltages to it?

Comment: You could use it for a bit, disconnect it, then immediately measure its resistance as it cools back down

Comment: *Should the coil itself be stretched out prior to usage?* <-- the coil turns should not touch each other in spurious ways.

Comment: @Andyaka Do you mean here "not touch so the length would become shorter" or if you compare [link](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Sc3a7dc3b10cc45db96024f9ef71f5396g/1Pc-220V-300-500-600-800-3000W-Oven-Verwarmingselement-Coil-Heater-Draden-kachel-Weerstand-Draad-Max.jpg_Q90.jpg_.webp) is too tight bonded and should be stretched apart?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean.

Comment: The Americans have mostly residual current circuit breaker. Is there a way to see is it stop the connection because of over-current or the error-current to ground-potential? Try a new circuit breaker and do the same test for comparison. Make sure the screws are all properly tightened.

Comment: @Andyaka if you answer the above, I'll mark it as the answer. When stretching the coil to gain spacing no issues with the circuitbreaker. Only downside is the wire being significantly longer than expected.

Comment: Are you saying the coils were actually touching @Skinkie

Comment: @Andyaka yes, I just took the delivered coil and connected 18V to it. When that worked (30 degrees Celcius), I tried 230V, that got the circuitbreaker to step in. When stretching the coil so the windings did not touch anymore the coil went red hot, but no effect on the circuit breaker. To be clear: the windings touched, I did not shorcut the coil by itself by folding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a comment discussion: -

@Skinkie the coil turns should not touch each other in spurious ways.

> *@Andyaka Do you mean here "not touch so the length would become
> shorter"*

@Skinkie Yes that's what I mean

> *@Andyaka if you answer the above, I'll mark it as the answer. When
> stretching the coil to gain spacing no issues with the circuitbreaker.*

Are you saying the coils were actually touching @Skinkie

> *@Andyaka yes, I just took the delivered coil and connected 18V to it.
> When that worked (30 degrees Celcius), I tried 230V, that got the
> circuitbreaker to step in. When stretching the coil so the windings
> did not touch anymore the coil went red hot, but no effect on the
> circuit breaker. To be clear: the windings touched*

That's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the probable reasons for 'nuisance tripping' of the circuit breaker :

1. The circuit breaker is faulty.
2. The circuit breaker terminal screw is loose.

   Loose contact could cause the circuit breaker to overheat and trip even
   though the heater current is much less than the rated current of the
   circuit breaker.